# Handle URLSession timeout

Tags: swift, timeout, session-timeout, urlsession

I am use URLSession for POST request and obtain list of players, but sometimes I am obtain error "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001", how I can handle it?

How I am get error inside "completion"?

```
func addPlayer(playerCode: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(url)") else { return }
    
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let playerCode = [playerCode]
    
    let params = ["players": playerCode]
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .init())
        
        urlRequest.httpBody = data
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5.0
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig).dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, resp, err) in
    
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard let resp = resp else { return }

            print(data)
            print(resp)
            
            guard let response = resp as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 530) ~= response.statusCode else {
                print("Error: HTTP request failed")
                return
            }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                print("Status code is 200")
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(ListOfPlayers.self, from: data)

                    // I am do what I am want

                
                } catch let jsonError {
                    print("Error json serialization \(jsonError)")
                }
                
                    completion(nil)
            } else if response.statusCode == 422 {
                print("Status code is 422")
                    completion(nil)
                return
            }
  
    }.resume()
    }
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Also I am try use this code:

```
 guard let err = err else { return }
            if (err._code == -1001) {
                print("Oops bad connection")
            }
```

but this code don't executed during "Time out"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can cast your error to `URLError` type and then use the `code` property to safely check if it's a session timeout error:

```
if (err as? URLError)?.code == .timedOut {
    // Handle session timeout
}
```